# Install Mini Pcie in Jetson Tk1

Tags: wireless, drivers, nvidia

I'm trying to run my wireless adapter in my embedded computer running Ubuntu 14.04 (Nvidia's Jetson TK1 Kernel: 3.10.24). The adapter is a miniPCIe board 7260 hmw. I was thinking that Ubuntu didn't have the correct drivers and tried unsuccessfully to install iwlwifi.

Later I discovered that under /lib/firmware I had three interesting files:

- iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
- iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
- iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode

These files made me think that iwlwifi is already installed. Then, I ran "lspci -v". 
Result:

`Network controller_ Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73)
subsystem: Intel corporation dual band wireless-ac 7260
flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 130
Memory at 32200000 (64 bit, non-prefetchable)[ size = 8K]
Capabilities: <access denied>`

The last line intrigues me and "Kernel driver in use" is not displayed.
So, my best guess is that I only have to add permissions and assign a driver that is already available in my computer, but how do I do that?

If I'm wrong, I'd appreciate your assistance.

Comment: I believe _iwlwifi_ doesn't cover your 7260 until kernel 3.13.0-xx. You could compile backports with some difficulty or upgrade. Capabilities will be displayed with sudo lspci -v, but are not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, Grinch kernel is required to use 7620.

See https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/766303/embedded-systems/-customkernel-grinch-19-3-1-for-jetson-tk1

Or (in Japanse)
http://green-rabbit.sakura.ne.jp/note/2014/08/16/jetson-tk1-use-intel-7260/